# Does a positive binary quadratic form represent a set of primes possessing a natural density

Tags: nt.number-theory, quadratic-forms

In his answer to my question 
[The Green-Tao theorem and positive binary quadratic forms](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28047/the-green-tao-theorem-and-positive-binary-quadratic-forms)
                Kevin Ventullo answers my initial question in the affirmative. What remains is the title question here, of separate interest to me.

Any integral positive binary quadratic form integrally represents a set of primes with known Dirichlet density. This is an application of the Cebotarev density theorem (or Chebotarev or Tchebotarev), in particular it is Theorem 9.12 in David A. Cox, Primes of the form $x^2 + n y^2,$ with the example $\Delta = -56$ on page 190. I typed this out in the previous question.

Now, Jurgen Neukirch "Class Field Theory" points to Serre "A Course in Arithmetic," and on page 76 Serre says that the set of primes p such that a fixed polynomial has a root $\pmod p$ has a natural density, and refers to K. Prachar "Primzahlverteilung" chapter 5 section 7. By results (theorem 9.2, page 180) in the Cox book, this means that the principal form 
$x^2+ny^2$ or $x^2+xy+ky^2$ does represent a set of primes with a natural density, therefore equalling the Dirichlet density. And by the result on arithmetic progressions, a full genus of forms has a natural density.

Combining observations, the principal form always has a natural density of primes, any full genus does, therefore we are done for one class per genus, and in the case of two classes per genus we are done with the principal genus and any genus with two distinct opposite forms. So we have natural densities for Cox's $\Delta = -56$ example. We are also done with the principal genus when it has three classes.

So, (and I would love a reference), does every positive binary quadratic form represent a set of primes for which the natural density exists?

Comment: Will, You should look at "Sets of primes determined by systems of polynomial congruences" ,
J. C. Lagarias, 
Illinois J. Math. 27 (1983), pp. 224-239.

Comment: Thanks, Victor. Robin is quite clear in his answer, but after Cox's book I am left with this sort of problem: given $\Delta = -47,$ I can tell if a prime with $ ( -47 | p) = 1 $ is represented by $ x^2 + x y + 12 y^2 $ by whether a certain $ f_{-47}(t)$ has a root $\pmod p,$ and I would love to know the monic degree 5 $ f_{-47}(t)!$ If not by the principal form, how can I tell whether $p$ is represented by 
$ 2 x^2 \pm x y + 6 y^2 $  or by  
$ 3 x^2 \pm x y + 4 y^2 ?$

Comment: Will, That's exactly what Jeff covers in his paper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Accoring to [H. Lenstra](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/Lenstra-Chebotarev.pdf), Chebotarev's theorem holds both for Dirichlet and
for natural density (but he doesn't give a reference in this document).
Applying Chebotarev to the extension $H/\mathbb{Q}$ where $H$ is the Hilbert
class field of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-n})$ gives the result you want.
(At least for primitive discriminants; for non-primitive discriminants
you need an appropriate generalization of the Hilbert class field).

**Added in response to Will's comment**
There is always a suitable field. Let $-D$ be a primitive negative
discriminant and let $d=-m^2D$ be a general discriminant. Let $H_n$
be the abelian extension of $K=\mathbb{Q}{\sqrt{-D}}$ where a non-ramified
prime splits iff its is principal and generated by an
element of $\mathbb{Z}+m\mathcal{O}_K$. Such a field $H_n$ is
called a *ring class field* and exists by class field theory. It also
is an extension of $K$ by a singular value of the $j$-function.

Then $G_m=\mathrm{Gal}(H_n/\mathbb{Q})$ is a generalized dihedral group.
There is a correspondence between conjugacy classes in $G_m$ and pairs
of equivalence classes of $ax^2\pm bxy+cy^2$ of discriminant $d$, such that
an unramified prime has its Frobenius in a conjugacy class iff it it
represented by the corresponding form. This is why we can apply Chebotarev.

**Even more added**
A good reference for ring class fields is Cox's book *Primes of the Form
$x^2+ny^2$*.

Comment: I used Google with "chebotarev density" "natural density". Our own Pete L. Clark, in some lecture notes, attributes the result for natural density to Hecke. www.math.uga.edu/~pete/8430notes5.pdf

Comment: @Will: yes, that's what I say.  I would be happy to have a precise reference though.  

Comment: I hope that I have managed to make genuine links by putting the string "http://" in front.
On the  Chebotarev density theorem proved for  natural density, 
Stevenhagen and Lenstra give a specific 1917 Hecke article   
http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hwl/papers/cheb.pdf    
    Then 
Anatoly Preygel        
http://modular.fas.harvard.edu/129-05/final_papers/Anatoly-Preygel.pdf    

refers to a modern book, 

Larry Joel Goldstein ,  Analytic Number Theory (1971)  

while I already mentioned K. Prachar "Primzahlverteilung" (1957)

so I am planning to go borrow more books from campus.   

Comment: There's an alternative to class-field theory here. For the most part
the argument is like that used nowadays for showing primes in a
progression have a relative density, but you have to use ray-class
characters in the ring of integers of the quadratic field. The hard
part is showing that the L-function attached to a real character
doesn't vanish at 1. Once one can extend the L-function to all of C, one can give a Landau style argument. What Hecke did was show how to
extend the L-function-- his argument is much like one of Riemann's;
Tate later put it in the modern style.

Comment: Dear Prof. Monsky, Could you please tell me where the Tate article appeared? Also, would you say that the Hecke results you mean appear in the piece Stevenhagen and Lenstra mention, Uber die L-Funktionen und den Dirichletschen Primzahlsatz fur einen beliebigen Zahlkorper, Nachr. Akad. Wiss. Gottingen Math.-Phys. (1917) pages 299-318 or Mathematische Werke, pages 178-197. Thanks in advance, Will.

Comment: I presume Prof. Monsky is referring to Tate's PhD thesis
which was published as an article in the classic collection
*Algebraic Number Theory* edited by Cassels and Frohlich.

Comment: Will--I was referring to Tate's thesis and the paper you mention. One
more remark. Supose O is the ring of integers in K, [K:Q]=n, m is a modulus and S is a ray class for m. Hecke shows that the prime ideals
of O in S have a Dirichlet density independent of S and a relative
natural density independent of S (cf. page 197). The second result is
no harder than the first once you know Hadamard's proof of PNT. For
Dedekind's method shows the L-functions extend to Re s >1-(1/n). So
the only problem is the real L at 1.        Paul

Comment: Thanks, Paul. Do you have any opinion on the questions I posed to Victor Miller after his comment (directly under the initital question)?

Comment: On page 195 of Hecke's paper in "Werke" he says he now can prove the
existence of prime ideals in every ray class "ohne dass wir dazu die
Existenz der zugehorigen Klassenkorper zu kennen brauchen" I gather
from this and his comments on page 197 that the proof via the
existence theorem only came 3 years later with Takagi. This seems
surprising since Hilbert had quadratic reciprocity for number fields
before 1900, and one only needs to construct the appropriate degree
2 extension, but Hecke is the expert.

Comment: Will--I tend to do what people since Lagrange have done; find an odd
b with b^2=-47 mod p, reduce the form px^2+bxy+cy^2 of discriminant
-47, and see what I get. But this probably isn't what you want. 

Comment: Thanks, Paul. That is the right way to do it in practice, of course. My first MO question was about the numbers integrally represented by 
$$ 2 x^2 + x y + 3 y^2 + z^3 - z,  $$ with a complete answer by Kevin Buzzard. I would love to investigate similar constructions in class number five, thus $\Delta = -47$ and a monic irreducible quintic $f_{-47}(t) $ related to the principal form (as in the Cox book) and 
then  an inhomogeneous polynomial, either
$$ 2 x^2 + x y + 6 y^2 - f_{-47}(t)  $$ 
or
$$ 3 x^2 + x y + 4 y^2 - f_{-47}(t) . $$

Answer (score 6):

If $Q$ is a positive binary quadratic form whose discriminant $D$ is fundamental, then the number of primes $\leq X$ represented by $Q$ is given asymptotically as

$\pi_{Q}(X)=\frac{1}{2h(D)} \mathrm{Li}(X)+O(X \exp{(-c_{Q}\sqrt{\log{X}})})$.

Here $\mathrm{Li}(X)$ is the usual logarithmic integral. My reason for giving this as an answer is to point out that this was proven by de la Vallee Poussin himself, in the same paper where he proved the usual prime number theorem!  Dating from the 1890s, this definitely predates Chebotarev, and de la V.P.'s contribution deserves (IMHO) to be better known than it is.  Hadamard's work on the PNT is a little easier on the reader than de la V.P.'s, but de la V.P.'s results were both stronger and more general, which sometimes is forgotten.

Comment: That's really nice, David. I think you need to multiply it by 2 if the form is not equivalent to its opposite, the coarse relations being that the sum over all must be (1/2) Li(X), while the total per genus should be independent of genus.

Comment: Hi Will, could you give an example of what you mean?  Does equivalent mean "represents the same integers"?

Comment: Sure. This is in the book by Cox, page 190. For discriminant $-56,$ both $ x^2 + 14 y^2$ and $2 x^2 + 7 y^2,$ which are ambiguous forms, get Dirichlet density, and natural density of primes, $1/8,$ to total $1/4$ for the principal genus. In the other genus $ 3 x^2 + 2 x y + 5 y^2$ and its opposite $ 3 x^2 - 2 x y + 5 y^2$ represent exactly the same numbers, and in particular prime density $1/4.$ Entire discriminant 
$ 1/4 + 1/4 = 1/2.$

Comment: @David Hansen: This is a very interesting answer, I happen to be looking for something exactly like this.  Can you explain how one would go about proving this, or do you know any books or papers where I can read the proof?  (Other then perhaps de la Vallee Poussin's original)  Thanks a lot!