# Submission of papers to ArXiv or similar

Tags: soft-question

This is an extension of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627180/submission-of-papers-to-arxiv-or-similar) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607895/asymptotic-formula-for-almost-primes) on MathStackExchange.

I have developed a formula for almost primes which is far more accurate asymptotically than Landau's well known

$$\pi_k(n) \sim \left( \frac{n}{\log n} \right) \frac{(\log\log n)^{k-1}}{(k - 1)!}$$

and I have a paper that I would like to submit to arXiv.org, whilst it is in the process of being reviewed (which I realise can take a very long time).

However, the submission guidelines say that it must be endorsed by someone currently affiliated with ArXiv. I have heard that it is possible to publish on  vixra.org, but that it is not really advisable.

I don't know whether this is an appropriate question to ask, but users on MathStackExchange have suggested that I ask here whether anyone would be willing to endorse a publication of the paper on ArXiv.

I am not affiliated with any university - I just have a (an over?!) healthy interest in the subject! Unfortunately, I do not know of anyone in the field, and am a little wary of  sending the paper to people I do not know.

Comment: I don't think that it is appropriate to use MO to ask for arXiv endorsements, so I have voted to close.  I saw on math.stackexchange.com that Igor Rivin told you he'd be willing to look at your paper.  I urge you to take him up on his kind offer.  I'm sure if he thinks it is correct and new that he will either be willing to endorse it himself or at least suggest other people who might be willing to.

Comment: OK - many thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: It will also be probably appropriate to ask here if your more exact formula is new, likely to be correct, etc. (while presenting it). I am not familiar with vixra.org but if you want your paper to be "recorded," and if there is no endorsement needed, I dont see why it is not advisable.

Comment: Oh, no, don't use vixra. Bad advice from Gil, since he is not aware of what appears there.

Comment: @GilKalai : vixra is basically arxiv for crackpots.

Comment: Many thanks for everyone's suggestions :)

Comment: You could also look at the answers to this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35927/asymptotic-density-of-k-almost-primes , or add your own answer to it.

Comment: I will certainly be only too happy to add my two-penny's worth once it has been verified.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know anything about almost primes, but I think you're mistaken not to send your paper to people in the field. If you're afraid of someone stealing your idea, I wouldn't worry --- having already submitted it to a journal establishes your priority (besides the fact that having your idea stolen seems very unlikely in this situation). A much more likely outcome is that your paper won't be read. However, if you do the research to find people who would be interested in this exact problem --- which, if you have internet, should be easy --- you increase the chance of being read. Being polite and asking for suggestions could also be more likely to produce a helpful response.

Most professional mathematicians are not interested in stealing your ideas, but are very interested in encouraging others who share similar interests. Approach others with this in mind.

Comment: Incidentally, I agree with Andy's comment about closing this question.  But since the question was upvoted so quickly I still felt it could be worth posting an answer.

Comment: As a non-mathematician, I have no idea of how the industry (for want of a better word) works, and am most grateful for the insights you provide. I find your comment about having already sent it to a journal reassuring, and would not have known this had you not told me. I realise that most mathematicians are interested in progressing knowledge in the subject, as you say, but unfortunately, whether in the field of mathematics or not, there are always exceptions to the rule!

Comment: I very much appreciate you providing an answer.

Comment: OK - I have sent it to Igor as suggested - again, many thanks :)

Comment: It's true that there are exceptions, but once you've put it out there the possibility of appropriation is virtually nil. Posting your formula here on MO, as Gil suggests, would also ensure priority. Good luck!

Comment: One more thing. Professional number theorists know an awful lot about primes. Be prepared for the possibility that your idea has already appeared somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I will, but it has been a lot of fun finding out about it anyway! - Thanks for the encouragement - I will see what Igor says (hopefully he will have the time to read it!), and then I will think about posting it here :)

Comment: @martin : please don't post it here.  it is well-established that it is not appropriate to use mo to publicize your work.  I think you are misunderstanding what Nik Weaver is saying.

Comment: Regarding your comment on vtc: Am I right to assume you will then not mind if this question and thus answer is deleted (in due course)?

Comment: @ Andy Putman, I understand - many thanks.

Comment: Incidentally, it was never my intention to use MO as a platform to publicize my work!

Comment: @martin : don't worry, I know that you have not tried to do so.  I just wanted to prevent an unpleasant situation from developing.  Good luck with your research!

Comment: Contrary to Nik's comment above, I've found out that some think MathOverflow is not worthy of establishing priority.  I recommend sharing with people you trust as well as using other mechanisms if priority is a concern.  Gerhard "Also Don't Forget About Simultaneity" Paseman, 2014.10.07

Comment: @ Gerhard Paseman, I am a little unsure what to take from this - I don't know what other avenues I can explore. Do you have any (explicit) suggestions?

Comment: @Martin, I'm a little puzzled by Gerhard's suggestion that MO is not "worthy" of establishing priority. You establish priority by documenting that you had the idea first. Period. If Gerhard knows of a case where an idea was credited to Mathematician B after Mathematician A had posted it on MO, and this situation was not immediately corrected, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Martin, I think you should preserve your wariness, and at the same time find someone you can trust.  My situation (which I prefer not to put on public display) involved finding someone I trusted and sharing results with them as well with some others.  This was good: the person I trusted is there for support, while some of the others did not; if push comes to shove, I have a witness AND data to back up my side of a priority fight.  The above avenues are what you need to do: I just suggest extra protection.  Gerhard "You Need Someone To Trust" Paseman, 2014.01.13

Comment: Nik, in the interest of doing no harm, I prefer not to detail my situation here.  Also, there are details which may not quite fit your description (credit goes to B after A posts on MathOverflow).  I am interested in your take on it, and will send you an email.  Gerhard "Sharing Conclusions, Not The Experience" Paseman, 2014.01.13

Comment: @Gerhard, okay, this sounds interesting.

Comment: @ Gerhard Paseman, thank you for the advice - I will try to adhere to it where possible. It may be of note to mention here that I have been very lucky in sending it to Igor, who has been most helpful.