# Maximizing sum of reciprocals of the elements of a subset of {1,2,..,n} subject to LCM(a,a')>n

Tags: nt.number-theory

In an answer to a previous MO question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227461/pruning-primitive-sequences-but-still-attaining-pillais-lower-bound-on-sum-of-r), MO user @fedja showed (by way of an upper bound) that if $A\subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$ has the property $LCM(a,a')\geq n+1$ for all $a\neq a' \in A$ then the biggest lower bound one can hope for is something like
$$
\sum_{a \in A} \frac{1}{a} \gg \sqrt{\log n}.
$$ 
I am wondering if a lower bound approaching this can be proved. Based on the linked question and also this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224995/primitive-sequence-a-i-attaining-pillais-bound-on-sum-i-1-a-i) where a set $\{a_i\}$ of primitive sequences ($1<a_1<\cdots<a_m<n$) none of whose terms divide another) are constructed attaining the bound
$$
\sum_{a_i} \frac{1}{a_i} \geq c \frac{\log n}{\sqrt{\log\log n}},
$$
this may not be hopeless. Any positive constant power $0<\delta\leq \frac{1}{2}$ of $\log n$ would do the job.

The set of primitive sequences formed by taking all $k-$wise prime products in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ for $k=[\log \log n]$ is quite substantial, and its intersection with the set of numbers satisfying the LCM condition may not be so sparse.

Any comments appreciated. The question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32988/density-and-sums-of-reciprocals) offers some more discussion in this general area, and links to other questions.

**Possible strategy:** I propose the following answer strategy (unrelated to primitive sequences) to obtain a lower bound. I would appreciate any comments, including proving this approach wrong.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be small. Clearly
$$
\sum_{n^{1-\varepsilon}< a \leq n}\frac{1}{a} \asymp \varepsilon \log n$$
holds. Now consider $a\neq a' \in (n^{1-\varepsilon},n] \cap \mathbb{Z}\stackrel {\triangle}{=} A(n,\varepsilon).$ We want to satisfy
$$
lcm(a,a')=\frac{aa'}{gcd(a,a')}\geq \frac{n^{2(1-\varepsilon)}}{gcd(a,a')}
>n, \quad \mathrm{or} \quad gcd(a,a')<n^{1-2\varepsilon}.
$$
To this end, we now remove multiples of small primes from the set $A(n,\varepsilon).$ Since the original cardinality of this set is $n-n^{1-\varepsilon}$, using Mertens' second theorem to approximate the Euler product tells us that after the process of removing these primes we now have a set $B(n,\varepsilon)\subset A(n,\varepsilon)$ with
$$
\#B(n,\varepsilon) = n(1-n^{-\varepsilon}) \prod_{p\leq n^{1-2\varepsilon}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\asymp n(1-n^{-\varepsilon})\frac{e^{-\gamma}+o(1)}{(1-2\varepsilon)\log n}.
$$ 
Now, for any $\epsilon'>0,$ we can make $n$ large enough to make $n^{-\varepsilon}<\epsilon'$ This should mean that 
$$
\#B(n,\varepsilon)\gg \frac{n}{\log n}.
$$
**Question:** Can't this be used to obtain (since the remaining set is well distributed in some sense)
$$
\sum_{a \in B(n,\varepsilon)} \frac{1}{a} \gg \log \log n?
$$

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: it should be "lower bound", fixed, thanks.