# Are numbers which are the product of n primes more common than numbers which are the product of n-1 primes?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

In a recent video (https://www.facebook.com/188916357807416/videos/519169035700435/) Stephen Wolfram wonders whether, for every integer n>2, eventually the number of integers which are precisely the product of n primes (not necessarily different) is greater than the number of integers which are precisely the product of n-1 primes. For n = 2, as he shows, this seems to be the case beyond somewhere around 10,000.
I am certain this has been studied and settled (Paul Erdös perhaps?), but don´t know where or by whom.

Comment: This is true for all $n\geq 1$. Asymptotics are known and are due to Landau, more details [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35927/asymptotic-density-of-k-almost-primes)

Comment: The main terms of these asymptotics suggests that the point at which $k+1$-almost primes overtake $k$-almost primes is around $e^{e^k}$.